# Query went from hours --> 4 seconds but I want to do better -- still have file sort

Tags: mysql, performance

I denormalized my system and went from a query that took hours to a query that takes 4 seconds. The table has 338,293 rows.

If I remove the group by and sum it takes .4 seconds; it is a lot faster; but then I have to process thousands of rows on the web server and have to send back a lot of data.

Is there any more indexing I can do or a way to make it faster and NOT use file sort or temporary tables?

Below is query along with schema.

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT item_name, category_id, category_name as category, sum(phppos_sales_items.subtotal) as subtotal, sum(phppos_sales_items.total) as total, sum(phppos_sales_items.tax) as tax, sum(phppos_sales_items.profit) as profit, sum(phppos_sales_items.quantity_purchased) as item_sold
    FROM `phppos_sales_items` FORCE INDEX (sales_search)
    WHERE `phppos_sales_items`.`sale_time` BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' and '2016-12-31 23:59:59' and
   `phppos_sales_items`.`location_id` IN (1) and 
   `phppos_sales_items`.`suspended` != 2
    AND `deleted` =0
    GROUP BY `category_id`
   LIMIT 500 

+----+-------------+--------------------+-------+----------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table              | type  | possible_keys                          | key          | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                                             |
+----+-------------+--------------------+-------+----------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | phppos_sales_items | range | phppos_sales_items_ibfk_5,sales_search | sales_search | 13      | NULL | 169146 | Using index condition; Using MRR; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+--------------------+-------+----------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and...

```
mysql> show create table phppos_sales_items;
CREATE TABLE `phppos_sales_items` (
  `sale_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `item_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rule_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rule_discount` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `serialnumber` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `line` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `quantity_purchased` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
  `item_cost_price` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL,
  `item_unit_price` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL,
  `regular_item_unit_price_at_time_of_sale` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `discount_percent` decimal(15,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `commission` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
  `is_bogo` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sale_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `suspended` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `was_layaway` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `was_estimate` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `store_account_payment` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `location_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `item_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `category_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subtotal` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
  `tax` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
  `total` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
  `profit` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
  PRIMARY KEY (`sale_id`,`item_id`,`line`),
  KEY `item_id` (`item_id`),
  KEY `phppos_sales_items_ibfk_3` (`rule_id`),
  KEY `item_name` (`item_name`),
  KEY `phppos_sales_items_ibfk_5` (`category_id`),
  KEY `sales_search` (`sale_time`,`location_id`,`deleted`,
                      `suspended`,`was_layaway`,`was_estimate`,
                      `store_account_payment`,`category_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_sales_items_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_items` (`item_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_sales_items_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`sale_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_sales` (`sale_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_sales_items_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`rule_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_price_rules` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_sales_items_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`location_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_sales` (`location_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_sales_items_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_categories` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Index Status:

```
mysql> mysql> show index from phppos_sales_items WHERE Key_name='sales_search';
+--------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table              | Non_unique | Key_name     | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| phppos_sales_items |          1 | sales_search |            1 | deleted     | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| phppos_sales_items |          1 | sales_search |            2 | location_id | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| phppos_sales_items |          1 | sales_search |            3 | suspended   | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| phppos_sales_items |          1 | sales_search |            4 | sale_time   | A         |      341905 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| phppos_sales_items |          1 | sales_search |            5 | category_id | A         |      341905 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: Add all the columns in the query to an index - bypasses the actual storage file completely.

Comment: can you please show me the output from **select * from phppos_sales_items procedure analyse();** and after this you can test to chenge key so that **delete** is the first field like ** KEY `sales_search1` (`deleted`,`sale_time`,`location_id`,`suspended`,`was_layaway`,`was_estimate`,`store_account_payment`,`category_id`)** thanks

Comment: @BerndBuffen when I do the procedure analyse() do you want me to do the entire query; or exactly what you typed (select * from phppos_sales_items procedure analyse())

Comment: @Chris Muench - exactly what i typed. its only to see how many different values are in each field. So you can delete all rows of the output from fields are not in the WHERE clause

Comment: @Chris Muench - which MySQL version you are using ?

Comment: mysql 5.6.33 is my version. The query with deleted first has the same explain and same query time.

Comment: here is results of analyse https://gist.github.com/blasto333/cab705964258184211cccba8f2f5bd7e

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134226/discussion-between-bernd-buffen-and-chris-muench).

Comment: @Chris Muench - first remove **FORCE INDEX (sales_search)**. it is always a bad idea to say the optimizer what to do. he can do the job better and if not rhe query or table is bad

Comment: @Chris Muench - i have generate a test table with 1.000.000 rows and your query use with group and without force index 6 seconds. after i add this index **ALTER TABLE phppos_sales_items add KEY `sales_search2` (`deleted`,`location_id`,`suspended`,`sale_time`,`category_id`);** it ONLY USE 125ms on my system

Comment: Still the same performance and still have to force index or it takes longer. Update the question to show index status

Answer (score 1):

so my answer is. I have tested it with a sample table with 1.000.000 rows and it use 6 sec before and 125 ms after this changes

1) remove the FORCE INDEX from your query

2) add a better key

```
 ALTER TABLE phppos_sales_items 
   add KEY `sales_search2` (`deleted`,`location_id`,`suspended`,`sale_time`,`category_id`);
```

Comment: Will give it a shot. Can you explain why better? Is it data dependent? Deleted is usually 0, location is is almost always 1 suspended is usually 0. So it don't see how it would filter faster. Is it because of the category id?

Comment: It filters faster because it does not need to look at those rows.  Granted, it is not a big savings, but it is something.

Comment: @Rick James - in this case the hole query can use the INDEX, the old index has some rows that are not used in the where clause or order by

Answer (score 0):

Shrinking size will help some, maybe a lot.  Do you really have 255-character serial numbers encoded in utf8?  Do you have commissions up to 9,999,999,999,999.9999999999 dollars (or Euros, or whatever)?  Etc.  `INT` is always 4 bytes, even if you say `INT(1)`; see `TINYINT`, which is 1 byte.

Don't start an index with a "range", put that column at the end.  For the query you quote, this would be better:

```
INDEX(deleted, location_id, sale_time)
```

Do you care which categories you look at?  Without an `ORDER BY`, you are not guaranteed which 500 you will get.

You are stuck with either a filesort or a big range scan; it is unclear which is worse.  You could add this to give the Optimizer a choice:

```
INDEX(deleted, location_id, category_id)
```

Yes, you could expand either of the indexes I propose to be 'covering'; this may help some more.  But it is important to start with the columns I mention, not `sale_time`.

**Analyzing the ANALYSE**

`sale_id` could be `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` (3 bytes)
`item_id` could be `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (2 bytes)
etc.
Don't use `ENUM` for the obviously numeric values.
Don't use `CHAR`; stick with `VARCHAR`.
Consider removing the always-NULL columns.
Do you really need 10 decimal places?
Profit of `-88004009373.3500000000`?  What??